# How about: Using a field containing all information to use it for search

Tags: database, search

On the Employees Database Table, I'm using field called **SearchTags** in that field i'm going to add the employees information like *FullName* + *PassportNo* + *Nationality* + *JobTitel* est.

And to search for a particular employee i'll search within that field (**TagSearch**)

What Do you think about this method?

isn't that considered as information duplicate?

from my opinion this method is very easy to code it and straight forward.

So, I'd like to know your opinion before I start using this method :)

Comment: that is some risky information to be storing all in one field as plain text. also, if your using mysql, look at fulltext indexing and searching

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that you are using SQL to perform the search.

**What Do you think about this method?**

I don't mean to sound harsh, but I completely disagree with your approach.

**isn't that considered as information duplicate?**

Of course, which is not at all recommended by database design fundamentals.

**Problems you will have to face**

- What if you want to update one of those individual fields? For example, when the job title changes, how will you handle? You will have to update at two places.
- A new requirement down the road will demand you to search only 3 of those fields, not four. What would you do? Create another field with duplicates of the latest 3 target fields?

SQL is simple enough to formulate a query to target multiple fields to search.

Comment: Thanks for your reply it was really helpful, you convinced me :)

Comment: Welcome, make sure that you follow Database Normalization rules 1,2,3, etc. Can be easily found on wiki. Sometimes, requirements demand you to violate those rules for performance gain. However, your scenario isn't that type, so better stick to the fundamentals.